# SQL Server error: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, insertion

I am trying to develop a sample registration page using ASP.Net and C#. I am calling a stored procedure to insert the data to database. My database is SQL Server 2008.

This is my code:

```
public partial class Sample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
   string str;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rbt_Male.Checked = true;
}

protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string @Name = txtbx_Name.Text;
    string @Gender_male = rbt_Male.Text;
    string @Gender_Female = rbt_Female.Text;
    string @Email = txtbx_Email.Text;
    DateTime @Dob = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_Dob.Text);
    submitdata();
}

protected void submitdata()
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "insertdata";

        if (rbt_Male.Checked)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtbx_Name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender_Male", rbt_Male.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtbx_Email.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dob", Convert.ToDateTime(txt_Dob.Text));
        }
        else if (rbt_Female.Checked)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtbx_Name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender_Female", rbt_Male.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtbx_Email.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dob", Convert.ToDateTime(txt_Dob.Text));
        }

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        lbl_Errormsg.Visible = true;
        lbl_Errormsg.Text = "Record Inserted Successfully";
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lbl_Errormsg.Visible = true;
        lbl_Errormsg.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

I am getting the error message

> *ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.*

I am getting this error at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Please help me.

My stored procedure is

```
ALTER Procedure insertdata
(
 @Name Varchar(20),
 @Gender Varchar(6),
 @Email Varchar(20),
 @Dob date
) 
As
 Begin
   Insert into samplelogintable (Name, Gender, Email, Dob)
   Values(@Name, @Gender, @Email, @Dob)
 End
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't associated your command `cmd` with your SqlConnection, that is why you are getting the error.

You need to specify:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

in your `submitdata()` method.

Since SqlCommand implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), its better if you use it within using block like:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "insertdata";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    .... your code

}
```

Comment: Just for confirmation, I have to write the code from "if (rbt_Male.Checked)" to the end of the try block, am I correct?

Comment: @Pritam, you can associate the connection with Command before its execution, you can even specify the connection in the constructor for command along with the command text. But just remember to associate the connection with the command before its execution

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am new to stackoverflow. Thanks for your suggestion. I'll keep this in mind in future.

Comment: I have some doubts now, if you are free, can you please let me know it? Actually I am facing some problem to insert some data to the database via stored procedure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pritam, I would suggest you to post a new question with all the possible details, including the c# code you are using and your SP call, and your SP if possible, or a small example with your problem. This would let other users on SO to help you in a better way.

Comment: Thanks. I am posting it now.